# Strange behaviour with Zend_Element 'belongsTo' property

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I've seen other threads and bug reports to do with the belongsTo property of an Zend_Element but nothing that relates directly to what i'm experiencing..

Here is my (simplified) Zend_Form:

```
$form = new Zend_Form();

$form->addElement('text', 'fname', array('belongsTo' => 'user'));
$form->addElement('text', 'sname', array('belongsTo' => 'user'));
```

Which is fine and the elements render like so:

```
<input type="text" name="user[fname]" />
<input type="text" name="user[sname]" />
```

...which is exactly what i want.

However, when the form is submitted, the element values are only accessible if you call

```
$form->getValue('fname') or $form->getValue('sname')
```

NOT, if you call...

```
$form->getValue('user');
```

What i'm expecting to see when you call $form->getValues('user') is an array of the values.
The array of values is clearly visible if you call

```
$form->getValues();
```

If this is the expected behaviour, then whats the point of putting them in an array? Because there would be no distinction between "user[fname]" and "client[fname]" - in fact adding another element with name "fname", even though it belongs to another item, would overwrite the previous.

I've tried adding a sub form which does result in what i want, but that way all the sub-form elements get rendered together, what i really want is to lay the 'array' elements in random places, like this...

```
<input type="text" name="user[fname]" />
<input type="text" name="some-other-field" />
<input type="text" name="some-other-field2" />
<input type="text" name="user[sname]" />
<input type="text" name="another-field-too" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$form->getValue('fname') or $form->getValue('sname')
```

works this way because *getValue()* is just looking for the name of the element, and the names of your elemnts are *fname* and *sname*.

```
 Excerpt: Zend/Form.php
 public function getValue($name)
{
    if ($element = $this->getElement($name)) {
        return $element->getValue();
    }
```

the way to access your *belongsTo* data from what I've seen should be:

```
$data = $form->getValues();
$user=$data['user'];
```

this should do what you want. Based on this:

```
Excerpt: Zend/Form.php  
public function getValues($suppressArrayNotation = false)
    {
        $values = array();
        $eBelongTo = null;

        if ($this->isArray()) {
            $eBelongTo = $this->getElementsBelongTo();
        }

        foreach ($this->getElements() as $key => $element) {
            if (!$element->getIgnore()) {
                $merge = array();
                if (($belongsTo = $element->getBelongsTo()) !== $eBelongTo) {
                    if ('' !== (string)$belongsTo) {
                        $key = $belongsTo . '[' . $key . ']';
                    }
                }
                $merge = $this->_attachToArray($element->getValue(), $key);
                $values = $this->_array_replace_recursive($values, $merge);
            }
        }
//...Code continues
return $values;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi RockyFord - thanks for your suggestion, but it still doesn't make sense - setting a belongsTo should set the element as a child (or subForm) of the one you're specifying it belongs to. Otherwise, if it just creates it as an individual element then there's no point in setting the belongsTo.

Comment: Depends on your point of view. getValue($key) is intended to return the value of a single element, regardless of any other setting. getValues() provides a means to return all values of a dataset as an array. The cool part of ZF though is that if you don't agree with their choices, change them. Extend Zend/Form and override getValue() with your own function.